# invalid multibyte escape after upgrade to rails 3 and ruby 1.9.2 -- dtext = '[^\\x80]'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am upgrading my app from rails 2 to 3 and when i 'require' this file that has an email address validator i get an 'invalid multibyte escape' error with:

```
dtext = '[^\\\\x80]'
pattern = /\A#{dtext}\z/
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
pattern = /\A#{dtext}\z/, nil, 'n'
```

Check out [details on encodings and regexp](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/miscellaneous_m17n_details) for more.

And I use and recommend this awesome article on [encodings in Ruby](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/17/encodings-unabridged/).

Comment: This is not working for me. The file he refers to is here https://github.com/wireframe/email-validator/blob/master/lib/rfc822.rb

Answer (score 0):

Modify the rfc822.rb file and change the addr_spec line to the following:

```
addr_spec = Regexp.new("#{local_part}\\x40#{domain}", nil, 'n')
```

That should resolve the issue. I got the solution from another gem, see https://github.com/saepia/rfc822/blob/master/lib/rfc822.rb